# get all APK files on api 29 programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage, android-10.0

I want to get all APK files on external storage on api 29.
Do you have any suggests?
Thanks

Note:on api 29 we can't get external Storage directory by:
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: For non-media files, like APKs, what you want basically is no longer possible. However, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and specify the APK MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`) to allow the user to choose an APK from external and removable storage, Google Drive, etc.